# Need helping moving data from one column to another

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dataset, multiple-columns

New to python and pandas and trying to figure this out.

I'm dealing with a data set that's pretty messy.  There are 500 rows and 9 columns.  In a few instances, data that should be in coulmn 9 has been indexed into column 8, along with column 8 data.

```
    ... Col 8          Col 9
 0     2 weeks         No. 13
 1     1 week          No. 2
 2  12 weeks, No 1
 3    15 weeks         No. 8
 4  7 weeks, No. 1
```

How can I separate the data and move to the proper column?

I applied a split(), but don't know how to move it over.
I'm thinking I need to use the apply(), but not sure on how.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`split()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True`, then [**`fillna()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill the missing values:

```
df[['Col 8', 'Col 9']] = df['Col 8'].str.split(',', expand=True).fillna({1: df['Col 9']})

#       Col 8   Col 9
# 0   2 weeks  No. 13
# 1    1 week   No. 2
# 2  12 weeks    No 1
# 3  15 weeks   No. 8
# 4   7 weeks   No. 1
```

Comment: That's awesome!  It worked.  Thanks.  Is there a way to remove the extra data from col 8?

Comment: @Faust_ARP32 I updated the answer. See if that works on your end.

Comment: Yes!  That did it.  Thank you so much!